# Halacha on the Parsha

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation

What Parsha ספרים are out there that aren't commentaries on the text per say, but rather Halachic Sugyas based on the Parshios (similar to Minchas Asher by Rav Asher Weiss)? In particular, I am looking for a work that takes one or perhaps several פסוקים from the Parsha and tells over a Sugya learned from that פסוק

Comment: Check out תיבת גמא

Comment: Consider narrowing the scope of this question, or breaking it up into multiple narrower questions.

Comment: @mevaqesh what is broad about the question?

Comment: There are many possible answers. And no sufficient criteria to identify the right one.

Comment: OK. I've edited it

Comment: Did Rabbi Mirsky write on חומש?

Comment: It still probably seems too broad...

Comment: @mevaqesh In my experience there actually aren't too many possible answers: seforim of this kind are not so common. Seems like a reasonably scoped question to me.

Comment: @Jay even were your limited experience actually indicative of a relative dearth, I still don't know how a correct answer could be identified.

Comment: @mevaqesh simple: find some seforim that match the OP's criteria. I don't understand the difficulty here.

Comment: @mevaqesh There are many questions that have more than one possible answer, if that's what's bothering you.

Comment: @Jay "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer" If you feel that other questions fail the site's criteria, VTC them.

Comment: @mevaqesh  He did indeed include enough detail to identify an adequate answer. The rule you're quoting doesn't say there must only be one correct answer.

Comment: @Jay You seem to making a derasha out of a simple sentence. Regardless, your personal views of site policy, without reference to FAQs or meta, , are not particularly useful, and certainly this is not the place for them. It is taken for granted that one answer can be identified as correct. as the site only allows for one post to be marked correct.

Comment: you may want to check out Kli Chemdah by Rabbi Meir Don Plotzky. He goes into great depth about Talmudic/Halachic subjects alluded to in each parsha .

Comment: @mevaqesh It's not a 'derasha' - I'm simply pointing out that you are incorrect: the rule you cited to support your claim is actually irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @mevaqesh Regarding your second point, here is a quote: "When a user receives a good answer to his or her question, that user has the option to "accept" an answer...Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally. Not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later." So you see, there can be multiple 'right' answers

Comment: @mevaqesh ...'accepting' an answer doesn't mean it is the one objectively correct answer to the exclusion of others - it just means the user liked that particular answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are many works in this genre. Some examples by contemporary authors: חבצלת השרון, which contains 7 volumes on Chumash; משנת חיים, which I believe is 5 volumes; הגיוני הפרשה--the first two volumes, [בראשית](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/46506) and [שמות](http://hebrewbooks.org/46507) are available on hebrewbooks.org; רנת יצחק and גבורת יצחק--multiple editions; אמרי חן, e.g., [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/51824); אור אברהם, contains 5 volumes, ברכת כהן, one volume. This is in addition to classic seforim such as פרשת דרכים, and כלי חמדה. R. Yosef Engel's seforim organized on the Torah, תפארת יוסף, of which three volumes are available, contain an abundance of halachah. One could also view מנחת חינוך in this way. (The בן איש חי is a halachah sefer organized by parashah, but I don't think the halachot connect to the parashah.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the *What If...* series from Artscroll ([Volume 1](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422613160.html), [Volume 2](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422615348.html), [Volume 3](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422617533.html)), or the corresponding *Veha'arev Na* series from Feldheim ([Volume 1](http://www.feldheim.com/veha-arev-na.html), [Volume 2](http://www.feldheim.com/veha-rev-na-vol-2-english.html)). Both take Rabbi Zilberstein's Chashukei Chemed (organized by related dapei Gemara) and rearranges them, usually only very loosely based on the parshah.

Comment: I thought they're both based on his sefer Vehaarev Na, which is on the parsha...

Comment: @robev Nope. What if clearly says it's adapted from Chashukei Chemed. Although I don't own Veha'arev Na, the cases presented on the cover are all from Chashukei Chemed, so I assumed the others were, as well. (Vehaarev Na is based on Vehaarev Na?)

Comment: Rav Zilberstein wrote a Hebrew sefer called Vehaarev Na on the parsha. Feildheim translated it into their english book Vahaarev Na (same title), see http://www.feldheim.com/veha-arev-na.html. I guess artscroll used a different sefer of his to write What If